# Material design theme color attributes not showing

Tags: android, xml, material-design

I am currently learning to use material design for android, I added the corresponding dependency :

**implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'**

Some attributes like colorPrimary and colorSecondary are showing but others (like colorPrimaryVariant and colorOnSecondary) are not

Are there any additional dependencies that I should add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there exists a newer version for material design which is not written in the documentation of material design,
so in case you are facing the same problem
change

**implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'**

to:

**implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha04'**